# How to script in Vim to yank only lines from a visual selection (or fold) that match a certain pattern?

Tags: vim

I'd like to add a command to my `.vimrc` that allows to, within a visual selection or the range of the current fold level to

- yank all, but only those lines that match a certain pattern.

and as a bonus to

- reverse their order

and

- perform a small pattern substitution.

---

Specifically the idea is to reduce the legwork in writing the common C idiom fail-goto-rollback, i.e. (can be found in lot of C projects most prominently the Linux kernel) if the body of a function (or a block) is this

```
    someErrorType errorcode;
    if(fail1) {
        errorcode = someError1;
        goto error_1;
    }
    prepare_a();
    if(fail2) { 
        errorcode = someError2;
        goto error_2;
    }
```

then the result of the desired transformation shall be this.

```
error_2:
    /* <insert cleanup code operation that did not fail1 here> */
error_1:
```

Answer (score 3):

for the "yanking all", you can do:

- normal mode: `qaq` to clear reg `a`
- do visual selection
- press `:`, vim will auto add `'<,'>`, then `g/pattern/y A<Enter>`

all your needed lines are in reg `a`, you can `"ap` to paste. for the reversing order requirement, I don't understand.  What output do you expect. A concrete before/after example may help.

Comment: I provided some idiomatic code. Essentially the idea is, that you rollback resource allocations in the reverse order you created them. So if there are failure rollback gotos to the labels 'a', 'b', 'c', the order of rollback operations would be 'c', 'b', 'a'. The replacement pattern would be `/goto(.*);/\1:/`.

Comment: @datenwolf I think I get what you wanted. A quick(but dirty) way would be `g/pattern/m 0` then matched lines are listed at the beginning of the buffer reversely, then you go to the beginning of the buffer edit the newly added block, remove `goto` and change the last `;` ->`:`.  This won't be difficult with vim magic (or macro). finally cut the block and paste to the right position. Another option is to write a function, first filter those matched lines from your selection into a list, reverse the list, do the substitution, write result into a register, so that you can paste somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

For adding boilerplate code, the usual solution is via a *snippets* plugin, which solves this (at least partially) in a generic way, instead of building a (possibly brittle) special solution with Vim built-ins.

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Comment: A qood answer, to the wrong question. I'm not asking about boilerplate snippets here, but dynamic text tranformation.

Comment: All snippets plugins support mirroring, so when you type the `error_1` label in the `if` statement, it'll be automatically inserted as a label below. At least UltiSnips also supports a transformation during that. I'd say that's close to what you want. (And much easier to implement than a custom transformation!)